# sfdx force:org:list --all doesn't show all scratch orgs

Tags: salesforcedx

After a few times executing `sfdx force:org:create` and getting an authentication error (related to .key file of jwt mechanism) I started to receive this error.

ERROR running force:org:create:  The signup request failed because this organization has reached its active scratch org limit

It's clear the scratch orgs were created. My problem now is when I run `sfdx force:org:list --all` no active scratch orgs are listed.

**Does somebody has any suggestion how to exclude these created sandboxes?**

They all were created from the same computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still get at the orgs and remove them even if your SFDX doesn't retain authentication details for the org.

Log in to your Dev Hub and open the Active Scratch Orgs tab, All Active Scratch Orgs list view. Locate each scratch org that's not present in your SFDX `force:org:list`, open its record page, and click the Delete button (you may need to select it from the Lightning additional actions drop-down).

That'll take care of removing the orgs for you prior to their expiration dates.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you David Reed!